# Busca e comparação de dados

Tags: java, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou necessitando realizar uma busca e elaborei o seguinte código para realizá-lo, porém sem sucesso. Gostaria de saber se estou fazendo do modo adequado.

```
public void AcessoCC()
{
    int id = 0;
    Integer infoConta;


    System.out.println("Informe o número da conta: ");
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    infoConta = sc.nextInt();

   for(int i = 0; i < clienteCC.length; i++)
    {
        if (clienteCC[i].getNumConta() == infoConta)
        {
            id = i;
        }
    }

    if (clienteCC[id].getCliente() != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Cliente: " + clienteCC[id].getCliente());
        System.out.println("Conta número: " + clienteCC[id].getNumConta());
        System.out.println("Cliente: " + clienteCC[id].getSaldo());
        System.out.println("Limite Disponivel: " 
                + clienteCC[id].getLimite());
        System.out.println("Limite Disponivel: " 
                + clienteCC[id].getLimiteTotal());

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Deseja: 'S'aque, 'D'eposito, 'V'er saldo"
                    + " ou 'E'ncerrar");


        }while(op != 'T');
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Dados não localizados");
    }
}
```

Comment: O que esse código deveria fazer que não está fazendo?

Comment: Poderia mostrar como são os objetos da **clienteCC** ? se possível edite sua pergunta e adicione a classe do Objeto Cliente! Poderia informar o que acontece? O que não funciona? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temos um pequeno bug no  seu código!

Mas não sei se é isso que você gostaria de relatar!

O que acontece se o usuário digitar uma conta que não existe? 
Ele sempre irá mostrar o primeiro!

Você inicia a variável `id` com `0`, e este valor é uma posição válida em uma lista!

Caso não encontre nenhum Cliente, ele sempre mostrará o primeiro usuário da lista (posição `0` da lista).

Para corrigir, inicie a variável `id` com `-1`;

E antes de exibir os dados, verifique se `id` é diferente de `-1`!

```
 int id = -1;

    ....
    if(id != -1){
          System.out.println("Cliente: " + clienteCC[id].getCliente());
            System.out.println("Conta número: " + clienteCC[id].getNumConta());
            System.out.println("Cliente: " + clienteCC[id].getSaldo());
            System.out.println("Limite Disponivel: " 
                    + clienteCC[id].getLimite());
            System.out.println("Limite Disponivel: " 
                    + clienteCC[id].getLimiteTotal());

            do
            {
                System.out.println("Deseja: 'S'aque, 'D'eposito, 'V'er saldo"
                        + " ou 'E'ncerrar");


            }while(op != 'T');

    }else{
       System.out.println("Dados não localizados");
    }
```

Mais uma dica!

Não há necessidade de iterar a lista até o fim! 
Caso você ache o cliente, pode sair da iteração;
Para isso utilize o break;

Exemplo:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < clienteCC.length; i++)
    {
        if (clienteCC[i].getNumConta() == infoConta)
        {
            id = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```